# How to preload image using javascript in razor syntax?

Tags: javascript, razor, preloader

I have tried in the following way for image preloading using JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">            
    function preloader() {

    heavyImage = new Image();

        heavyImage.src = "../../Images/WFS_Homepage_GlobalServerNetwork_Transparent.jpg";

    }            
</script>

<body  onload="javascript:preloader()" >

<a href="#" onmouseover="javascript:document.img01.src='../../Images/WFS_Homepage_GlobalServerNetwork_Transparent.jpg">
<img src="../../Images/index.jpg" name="img01" />
</a>
```

But not getting any idea.How can i call JavaScript function in HTML .And how can i use preloaded images for further processing.I am trying it in asp.net mvc 3 Razor

Comment: What exactly you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: <body onload="preloader()"> not supported in razor why when i call function in html

Comment: `onload` if a function to call [when the document has *finished* loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body#attr-onload), it makes no sense to "preload" anything at this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var preloadImages = [
        '@Url.Content("~/Content/img/firstImage.jpg")',
        '@Url.Content("~/Content/img/secondImage.jpg")',
        '@Url.Content("~/Content/img/thirdImage.jpg")',
      ],
      images = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < preloadImages.length; i++){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = preloadImages[i];
    images.push(img);
  }
</script>
```

Which you could place in the `<body>` of your document (anywhere).

Comment: how do i use these preloaded images and i.e on mouse-hover how do i show these preloaded images from browser cache

Comment: How do i download these preloaded images in asp.net mvc 3

Comment: like images how can we preload fonts using java script .Do any one have idea ?